# find facebook matching post in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-fql

In my iOS app, I am posting some information on user's facebook wall, now I want to find out the similar post on wall of user's friends posted by same app, or match the text on user's wall with his friend's wall and then if match find out read the information of friend and whole post on friend's wall, currently am using facebook sdk for iOS.
please suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: Could you do a request for the wall posts, parse the JSON object, then do a for each to iterate over the content of each post and compare the string with what the user submitted?

Comment: Please, could you tell us where you are stuck ? Do you need help finding user's friends ? Accessing their wall ? Parsing their posts ? etc.

Comment: Yes, I know only to find friend list of user, but i don't know, how to read post from each friend, and how many post i can read ?, each friend have many posts and user have many friends, so scanning each post of friend is not very time consuming ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is done by steps ; 
1- you should gain the permission to user's friends walls.
2- you should then catch their posts (practically consumptive) and compare your user's post with them regarding the same app.
3- you have two options , a- you got the same post on one of user's friends wall,
                            - you catch the user and got it's required information.
                          b- you do not find out any match ,
                            - you return "No match found " message or (404- not found ).

1-
 `

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_status",@"friends_status",
                        @"friends_about_me",@"friends_activities",
                        nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: .....
```

`

2-
 `

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,status,picture,birthday,location"];
 [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
    if ("Your user status" == [friend status]){
       NsLog(@"friend @%,@% .. ",[friend name],[friend birthday], .... 
     }else {
        NSLog(@"No match found");
      }
}}];
```

`